# Identify diode part number

Tags: diodes, identification

This is a diode from a small 5 Vdc power supply that is part of a powered subwoofer.  Main supply voltages of about plus minus 45 Vdc look to be okay but the little 5V supply appears to be dead.

A quick check shows that this diode is shorted.  Markings are (top) V1H  (bottom) P133L

Google isn't much help (or I'm using the wrong search terms).  Closest I can see is a Turkish supplier website that suggests this is a 100V 3A part.  However, no hint of speed.

[image: Unknown Diode]

Any suggestions of what this might be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can hack in your own brand new 5v supply of you can find where the burned-out one was fed, but keep in mind there could be a good reason the oem 5v reg died, like something downstream failing short.

Comment: That was going to be my 2nd choice.  Goodness knows how many times I've done exactly that previously.  I actually keep a stock of small 5V 3A 90..250 Vac power supply modules on hand for just that situation.  But I'd like to fix the existing supply if all it takes is a diode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first item that a quick google of "diode V1H" throws up is [this site](https://www.datasheetarchive.com/DIODE%20V1h%20marking%20code-datasheet.html)
Scrolling down a bit you find a section headed "DIODE V1h Marking Code Datasheets Context Search".
Follow the link to the data sheet PDF.

Comment: I had found that site but the devices listed in the page that is visible in my browser are for a quad TVS in a 6-pin package.  It did not occur to me to scroll way further down the page.  Lesson learned!

Comment: So that part appears to be a 2.1A 60V Shcottky diode.  Many thanks!

Comment: @DwayneReid Yes, a Schottky diode fits what we know about the circuit (low voltage power supply). It sounds highly likely.

Comment: This diode is in the primary side of the supply.  Unfortunately, the traces dive underneath the transformer.  I **can** trace it but it will be a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 1):

- Manufacturer: Vishay Intertechnology, Inc
- Manufacturer part number: VS-10BQ060PBF (obsolete!!)
- Data sheet: [click](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/905/VS-10BQ060PbF.pdf)

[image]

- Manufacturer part number (substitute): VS-10BQ060-M3
- Data sheet (substitute): [click](https://www.vishay.com/docs/93357/vs-10bq060m.pdf)
- Distributor link (substitute): [click](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vishay-general-semiconductor-diodes-division/VS-10BQ060-M3-5BT/4933508?s=N4IgTCBcDaIGoGUC0BGADAIQIpoGxqQFkBmAegFYMAVEAXQF8g)
- Part type: Schottky rectifier